# How to make a text field appear when you click a button in swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am making a citation builder application which includes asking for authors' names. I want a button that when tap will make another text field appear to ask for another author's name. Is there anyway I can do this?

Similar to "add phone number" in the below example :

[image: kind of like the "Add phone number" in this example]

Comment: You mean when tapping the `(+)` and appears another line with the text field?

Comment: yes just like that

Comment: In your example it's a tableView with different cells. In the phone cell you have a button to add/remove data. It's not really hard to do.Please send more informations about your ViewController if you need more help.

Comment: the + button just triggers on tap and add 1 more cell to the tableView.

Answer (score 0):

Get the textField you want to appear and call `textField.becomeFirstResponse()` when the button tapped.

Comment: textField.becomeFirstResponder()

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this you can just add a new row in an `UITableView` using [insertRows(at:with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows). If you need help on how to do this please share more information about how your `UIViewController` is set up and share a screenshot of your app(if the one you provided is not that).